# How to catch parse exceptions in antlr4 using C++?

Tags: c++, antlr4

I'm using antlr4 c++ target. I don't know how to catch the parse exception, and cannot find a document about it.

I have tried using `parser.setErrorHandler(std::make_shared<antlr4::BailErrorStrategy>());`, but it throws an exception whose "e.what()" is empty.

```cpp
try {
    ANTLRInputStream instream(sql);
    MyLexer lexer(&instream);
    CommonTokenStream tokens(&lexer);
    MyParser parser(&tokens);
               // parser.setErrorHandler(std::make_shared<antlr4::BailErrorStrategy>());

    auto ctx = parser.singleStatement();
    ...
    } catch(ParseCancellationException& e) {
        std::cout << string(e.what()) << std::endl;
        throw MyParseException(e.what());
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
```

I expect to catch the exception message like "line 1:19 missing ';' at ''", and rethrow it using my own exception type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ParseCancellationException`s do not contain any information about the encountered syntax error, so they're not suitable for error reporting. The `BailErrorStrategy` is really only intended for scenarios where you don't want to report errors.

Instead you should stick with the default error handling strategy and register your own error listener (after removing the default one with `removeErrorListeners` unless you want error messages to still be printed to stderr in addition to whatever you're doing to report and/or handle the errors). The error listener will be called with all the information needed to properly report the error. You can then either directly throw an exception with that information or you can store the error info in a vector and then throw an exception containing information about *all* syntax errors after the parser finished.

Answer (score 2):

There are no parse exceptions you can catch. The `ParseCancellationException` is very special, as it is used to implement an early-exit strategy (usually used in conjunction with the 2-phase approach to start parsing in SLL mode (which is faster for syntactically correct input) and continue with LL mode, if the first phase fails. The exception is made so that it bypasses all catch clauses that normally kick in on parse errors.

The correct way to catch parse errors is (as sepp2k already mentioned) by adding your own error listener, which gets called with all necessary info (position, offending token etc.) so that you can create your own errors for the user.

I've implemented that approach in MySQL Workbench. Check the code [for the parse step](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/modules/db.mysql.parser/src/mysql_parser_module.cpp#L253) and [lexer](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/modules/db.mysql.parser/src/mysql_parser_module.cpp#L302) as well as [parser error](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/modules/db.mysql.parser/src/mysql_parser_module.cpp#L396) handling there.